# How do I create nested windows in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, graph, tkinter

I want to create a window inside a window. The outer window is just plain and the inner window is a graph. The reason for it is that I would like to make a monitoring system with multiple graphs where nested windows would help.

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import Tkinter

x = []
y = []

top = Tkinter.Tk()

top.title("Hello tkInter");
top.geometry("1000x1000")

fig=plt.figure()

rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')

readFile = open('sampleCSV.csv','r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    if xAndY[0] != '':
        x.append(int(xAndY[0]))
        y.append(int(xAndY[1]))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1, axisbg='grey')
ax1.plot(x, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='c')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='c')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax1.set_title('Matplotlib graph', color = 'c')
ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2, axisbg='grey')
ax2.plot(x, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors='c')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='c')
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax2.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax2.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax2.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax2.set_title('Matplotlib graph', color = 'c')
ax2.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax2.set_ylabel('y axis')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, axisbg='grey')
ax3.plot(x, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', colors='c')
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', colors='c')
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax3.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax3.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax3.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax3.yaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax3.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax3.set_title('Matplotlib graph', color = 'c')
ax3.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax3.set_ylabel('y axis')

plt.show()

fig.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

I am not able to figure out a solution to this. Please HELP!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window inside window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764908/window-inside-window/32397909#32397909)

Comment: Thank you Steven. This will definitely help !

Comment: I've updated the code on the aforementioned question if you'd like to check back on that.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [good SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Too much code, no error traceback, no question.  However, I believe your problem is that matplotlib and tkinter are not compatible, at least not without lots of work.  If plt.show() actually runs, I expect that since `fig` is a `matlab.pyplot.figure()` or `Figure` instance, and that class does not have a tkinter pack method, `fig.pack()` raises an AttributeError.