# Manipulating multiple tkinter windows from the main GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to build a simple image manipulation program in Python Tkinter. Is it possible to create a GUI which is capable of opening multiple TopLevels and can perform operation on the image from the most recently active Window?

This is the code so far:

```
def AddImage():
    while True:
        try:
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Choose file",filetypes=[("Images", "*.jpg *.png *.tif *.bmp")])
            image = Image.open(filename)
            image = image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            window = tk.Toplevel()
            window.title(filename)
            window.geometry('300x300')
            canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=300, bg='#D4D4D4')
            canvas.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
            canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor='nw')
            canvas.image = image
            break
        except AttributeError:
            break
def Init():
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_menu = tk.Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=my_menu)
    my_menu.add_command(label='Open File',command=AddImage)

    master = tk.Canvas(root, width=1200, height=600, bg='#D4D4D4')
    master.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Now, after opening a few images I want to do something with one of them, e.g. duplicate from the main interface.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are opening images in different windows and then trying to keep them on top-level of screen (in front of your root window),select them, and switch between the windows.

1. Lengthy method: **"Windows inside root window"**
   By some work arounds , you can create the sub-windows containing
   images inside the root window where they cannot get out of the root
   window's bounds.  Refer to
   [Window inside window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764908/window-inside-window)

   Basically, using image_window.transient(root) [where image_window is
   the window with image] will keep those sub windows on top of the
   root. Then, using conditional statements to keep the sub windows
   inside root. Finally, you can try using window.focus_force()
   wherever required in order to set a particular window in focus.
2. **Don't open images in new windows**- create frames with their own some custom bindings that allow you to move it around the root using place geometry manager. In the frame(s), open the images you want to.